# Make movie with data files using gnuplot

Tags: c++builder

I do have many data files. They look  like 
1.dat
2.dat
....
....
1000.dat

I want to make a movie using these files plotting them in sequence.
Does anyone have any idea please?
It would be my great pleasure if you can help me.
ND

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need two steps here. The first one is to create jpeg or png plots from the data.
I do not know what your data looks like, but I guess you've already found out how to plot it with gnuplot. Gnuplot has a loop option, but if you're on a linux box, you can easly pass all the files to gnuplot as arguments
for example, run the following in bash:

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
   gnuplot "What needs to be done" $i.dat
done
```

Now, you need to create your movie. The easiest way would be:

```
ffmpeg -i gnuplotoutput%04d.jpeg movie.mpeg
```

Edit:
After your clarification (the data is 3d etc):

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
   gnuplot -e "set terminal jpeg; splot '$i.dat'" > pic$i.jpeg
done

ffmpeg -i pic%04d.jpeg movie.mpeg
```

Indeed, the idea was that "what needs to be done " will be replaced by your own commands. gnuplot is exceptionally capable, but you need to tell it exactly what to do. That depends on your data, and what output you want. I've used splot, to create a [3d grid graph](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/plot3d2-e.html#6.6).

Comment: Thank you Jarondl. I do have still some problem in it. When I try ffmpeg it says for example"FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.1-4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al. configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.1-1ubuntu1 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf"and "libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Mar  4 2010 12:41:55, gcc: 4.4.3
pic%04d.jpg: I/O error occurred
Usually that means that input file is truncated and/or corrupted."
What do you think of this? I am running program in UBUNTU.

Comment: I got it. Thank you. But the second step has to be

Comment: ffmpeg -f image2 -i %d.jpeg video.mpg

Comment: Hi Jarondl. MAy you tell me how can I contron the timing of the movie please? It is going so fast that looks weired. I want to make it slow so that I could see the complete pattern. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi @nagendra .You can control the timing with the `-r` flag, which decides the frame-rate. I believe the default is 25 frames per second. If you want your movie to be much slower, say 10 frames per seconds, you can add `-r 10` to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: Dear Jarondl Thank you so much. I got it. I do have next issue of plotting a no of plots together. Here one blocks the other. I tried with the way how Gnuplot tutorial says<http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/transparent.html> but I could not get it. Even the codes there do not work. Do you have any idea you can share please?