# GNUPlot - Plot 2D datapoints as MPEG

Tags: gnuplot

I have a bunch of points in an x-y column, which I made using a bit of fortran code. Part of it looks like this

```
   1.000          0.000
   0.996          0.063
   0.988          0.125
   0.976          0.187
   0.961          0.249
   0.941          0.309
   0.917          0.368
   0.890          0.426
   0.859          0.481
   0.825          0.535
   0.787          0.587
   0.746          0.636
   0.702          0.682
```

and so far, I can plot it all in one image.

But what I need to do is to plot the points, one at a time, as a movie. I'd rather not do GIF, as I need the time slider. As it moves, I need to have lines connect the dots.

However, all the tutorials I've found that involve MPEGs are plotting it one DAT file at a time, and making the JPEGs into the film. Like this one, [Make movie with data files using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728708/make-movie-with-data-files-using-gnuplot), but I don't have enough resources for that.

Alternatively, I tried to follow this: [Gnuplot - plotting position(xyz) vs time data inside a specified space (eg a box) with a pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638636/gnuplot-plotting-positionxyz-vs-time-data-inside-a-specified-space-eg-a-box) and then convert it to MPEG, but I can't get their code to work. I get the full plot in all frames, and only the n=# part is animating.

I was able to get a "plot f(x, t)" animated, though.

(edit: i have no code to animate the points. really)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate one point at a time, you can do it as follows:

```
# calculate the number of points
stats 'file.txt' using 1:2 nooutput

# if you want to have a fixed range for all plots
set xrange [STATS_min_x:STATS_max_x]
set yrange [STATS_min_y:STATS_max_y]

set terminal pngcairo size 800,400
outtmpl = 'output%07d.png'

do for [i=0:STATS_records-1] {
    set output sprintf(outtmpl, i)
    plot 'file.txt' every ::::i with lines title sprintf('n = %d', i)
}
set output
```

and finally use something like

```
ffmpeg -i pic%07d.png movie.mpeg
```

to convert to a movie.

Note, that with `plot` you must use `every ::::i` (only four `:`) to limit the number of plotted points. The question you linked, [Gnuplot - plotting position(xyz) vs time data inside a specified space (eg a box) with a pause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11638636/2604213), must use five `:` to iterate over data *blocks*, like the are used for 3D-plots with `splot`.

Comment: What ARE the colons for, anyway? Also, would it be possible to skip the first line about calculating points? My program can print that out, anyway.

Comment: @Vardonir The colons serve as data selectors. `help every` gives you detailed info. You can skip the first (or any other) line using `every`. For example `every :::0::1` selects the first two *blocks* of data, whereas `every ::0::1` selects the first two lines. `every ::1` skips the first line and plots everything else. Very powerful but a bit confusing at the beginning IMO.

Comment: Of course you can skip the calculation of the points. Then you must get the number of iterations from somewhere else. Also you must decide if the x- and y-ranges should be fixed for all plots, or if you want them to adapt from one plot to the next. I would suggest you to use a fixed range in which case you need to use `stats` anyway.

Comment: It worked! Thank you! FFMpeg was strangely hard to get up and running, though (the usual "sudo apt-get install..." didn't work), but I got it to work.